# For loop passes qualifying element ID to another function but in that function it's the entire HTML element not just ID, why?

Tags: javascript, html, materialize, toast

I have two functions, the first checks for all fields that have the required attribute and are empty. If that is true a "toast" (from Materialize CSS) notifies the user that X field is required and provides a link to focus on that field which when clicked focuses on the field.

I have got it working, but I am confused as to WHY it even works the way it does. I pass **bugElems[i].id** to the second function and when I log it in the first it shows what I expect: the ID of the element I am looking at. When I log the argument from the second function it shows me the entire HTML element itself with all it's attributes, not just the ID, as I would expect it work. I feel like I am being redundant but that's what Javascript seems to want.

```
function validateFields() {
  var bugForm = document.getElementById("bugForm");
  var bugElems = bugForm.elements;
  for (i = 0; i < bugElems.length; i++){
    if(bugElems[i].value === '' && bugElems[i].hasAttribute('required')){
      M.toast({
        html: bugElems[i].previousElementSibling.innerHTML + ' is required' + '<button class="btn-flat toast-action" onclick="toastFocus(' + bugElems[i].id + ')">Goto</button>',
        displayLength: 5000
      });
      console.log(bugElems[i].id,bugElems[i]);
    };
  }
}

function toastFocus(e) {
  console.log(e.id,e);
  document.getElementById(e.id).focus();
}
```

The log in the **validateFields()** function shows the following:

```
caseNumber <input type="text" id="caseNumber" required="">
```

And the log under **toastFocus()** function show the exact same:

```
caseNumber <input type="text" id="caseNumber" required="">
```

Again, I have it working as I want it with it's current iteration but I don't understand why it works. I am passing **bugElems[i].id** to **toastFocus** and then having to ask for the ID again because it gave me something else. Please help me understand, thank you.

**Edit:**

I kept tinkering and changed the code a bit to three functions, making it so the first toast does not have a button and auto-focuses (again, everything works as desired still). That one seems to pass the element ID as I would expect it to but it's not wrapped in the Materialize CSS object HTML thing-a-ma-jig. The whole mess now looks like this:

```
function validateFields() {
  var bugForm = document.getElementById("bugForm");
  var bugElems = bugForm.elements;
  var x = 0;

  M.Toast.dismissAll();

  for (i = 0; i < bugElems.length; i++){
    if(bugElems[i].value === '' && bugElems[i].hasAttribute('required')){
      if(x == 0){
        M.toast({
          html: bugElems[i].previousElementSibling.innerHTML + ' is required',
          displayLength: 5000
          });
        toastFocus(bugElems[i].id);
        x++;
      } else {
        M.toast({
          html: bugElems[i].previousElementSibling.innerHTML + ' is required' + '<button class="btn-flat toast-action" onclick="toastFocusClick(' + bugElems[i].id + ')">Goto</button>',
          displayLength: 5000
        });
      }
    };
  }
}

function toastFocus(f) {
  document.getElementById(f).focus();
}

function toastFocusClick(e) {
  M.Toast.dismissAll();
  document.getElementById(e.id).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the logs of **validateFields()** and  **toastFocus()** function shows the same element, but then you said:

> I am passing bugElems[i].id to toastFocus and then having to ask for the ID again because it gave me something else.

Can you clarify this?

Comment: The logs each show the ID of the element and then the entire HTML element. Each log is asking for the element.id and then just the element. However what I am passing to the second function is element.id. So if I am logging it why is it logging the entire HTML element when I am only trying to give it the ID? Sorry, hope that makes sense.